# is there any log for unhandled exceptions throwed by ASP.net applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

As title. I noticed that IIS will return 500 error, but is there any other log in the IIS side?

Answer (score 4):

check this one, [ELMAH: Error Logging Modules and Handlers](http://www.raboof.com/projects/Elmah/).

Answer (score 3):

Asp.net will also post an error to the application event log, but your better off using elmah or some other way of handling the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable Failed Request Tracing. [Example and instructions here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Health Monitoring.  It is flexible, and provided out-of-the box.  You just need to configure it.

http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs